# Is there a limit on the number of WHERE conditions in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause

How many number of `WHERE` clauses can be included in a `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an [IN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) for a query like that - it's more compact and signals your intent better.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN('asd', 'bsd', 'csd', ...);
```

Another alternative would be to create a table to do a left join against to filter out the rows you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

No, But read [here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to `SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH` which defaults to 1000000. You can redefine this limit to be as large as the smaller of `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` and 1073741824.